# Getting household income data based on address to block level?

Tags: data, census, address, united-states

I am beginning a research project and need to find a way to access the census data about household income.  We need it at a closer level than by zip code since income varies a lot by zip code in our area.

Is there a way to get household income based on address or at least down to the block level?

Answer (score 3):

The absolute highest geographic resolution for household income that is publicly available is at the block group level. The Census Bureau has provided an easy resource for this information [here](https://www.census.gov/tiger-data). Be careful, though, this level of geography suffers greatly from margin of error issues. I would recommend pulling information at the census tract level.