# Seeking Demographic Information of U.S. Census Blocks

Tags: data, united-states, census

I am struggling to find the blockwise (not blockgroup or tract) data like employment status, household income, commuting distance, list of place of interest, industry information. By using American Factfinder I get easily the updated data of these factors by tract and 2010 version of blockgroup. ACS Employment Status Data by Block Group, 2006-2010 is given [here](http://www.census.gov/people/laborforce/about/acs_employ.html).

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [Data Dictionary](http://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/LODESTechDoc7.0.pdf) for how to use the [Longitudinal Employer-Household Dynamics](http://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/) dataset.

The Workforce Area Characeristics (WAC) data files can tell you about information from the location of the employer's Census Block location. You might be able to get industry information from there.

Using the Residence Area Characteristics (RAC) data files, you can find the distribution of people making below $15,000 a year, between $15,000 and $40,000, and more than $40,000.

Finally, using the LEHD Origin-Destination (OD) data files you might be able to calculate commuting distance with Census Block centroids by either a simple distance measurement or network analysis.

All of the geographic codes correspond to shapefiles [here](http://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010/TABBLOCK/2010/).

Answer (score 1):

Some of the data you are seeking isn't released at the block level in order to protect privacy - it is only available aggregated to the block group level or higher.

See [Getting household income data based on address to block level?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71115)